# @HostListener for Auto fill an input field in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

On a form when I do select Auto fill, all the `input` fields get populated with values in which I'm having an issue with the *phone number* `input` field. The value that gets populated is `1233211232` with the Auto fill.

I have a custom directive which converts phone number into this format `(123) 321-1232` whenever user enters manually in the `input` field. But with Auto fill, the `@HostListener` block doesn't seem to be working. How do I detect the change in the `input` field?

```
export class PhoneDirective {

  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('click', [`$event.target`])
  onClickCalled(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event.value, true);
  }

  onInputChange(event, backspace) {
    if (event == null) {
      return '';
    }
    let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (backspace && newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
    }
    if (newVal.length === 0) {
      newVal = '';
    } else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1)');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '($1) $2');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 10) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10);
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
    }
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);
  }
}
```

This is the Regex for phone number I'm using

```
const isPhoneNumberValid = (/(\W|^)[(](?!000)\d{3}[)]{0,1}[\s-]{0,1}\d{3}[\s-]{0,1}\d{4}(\W|$)/).test(control.value);
```

Could anyone please help?